# new to android - understanding HashMap&lt;String,

Tags: java, android

I have been going through the [following tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) and came across this line of code which I have no idea what it means:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
```

I know what a hashmap is, 
what I don't understand is what is <  , ();   , and Element

Comment: No, please do *not* edit. This is *as shown in the code*. Follow the link! It's no wonder the OP is having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good catch, Jon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial is just badly (horribly!) formatted - too many levels of HTML escaping. Someone didn't take nearly enough care over their post... It *should* look like this:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) 

... later on ...

HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Now this *may* not make much more sense to you yet, but at least it's proper Java code :) This is using generics - [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a *generic type* with two type parameters - one for the key and one for the value. So in this case, it's a map from string to string (i.e. strings are used for both keys and values).

Read the [Generics part of the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information.

The code provided isn't idiomatic Java code in terms of its use of `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, mind you. Typically you'd declare variables using the *interfaces* and only use the concrete classes when constructing the objects. For example:

```
Map<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Given what I've seen of the tutorial so far, I'd suggest trying to find a better one...

Comment: thanxs for the info, can you tell me what is this Element stuff?

Comment: @user3134565: It's XML. I suspect you would make more progress if you actually took a step back and started with simple Java... I think you've bitten off a bit more than you can chew, not helped by the poor tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; map = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
```

Decode version

```
HashMap<String, String>; map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
```

`&lt;` represent <

`&gt;` represent >

This is improper HTML coding

Comment: what is the element object  ?